# Add alphabet counter to beginning of each line

Tags: bash, perl, sed, converters

I would like to add a counter to each line in a text file which is indexed over the alphabet. Are there any straight forward ways of doing this? For instance, if my text file looks like this

```
textAblabla
textBblabla
textCblabla
...
textABblabla
textACblabla
```

it should be converted into

```
A textAblabla
B textBblabla
C textCblabla
...
AB textABblabla
AC textACblabla
```

EDIT: It should be noted that it may very well be the case that each line is distinct. I now highlight this since it seems that my original question has caused some confusion.

EDIT 2: I do not want to print the list, I want to modify (overwrite) the original file with the enumeration.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: What did you try so far? Your above information doesn't help. You need to give some sample examples to identify `text` part and the counter part `A`, `AB`

Comment: The point is that I want to enumerate each line in a text file using the alphabet as my counter. I have seen many examples of how to do this using arabic numbers, but for my purposes I need to use the alphabet as my counter.

Comment: For instance, I have read about a function called nl in coreutils in Linux, but I do not think it supports enumeration using the latin alphabet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Perl:

```
perl -e '$x=A; while (<>) {print $x++." $_";}' file
```

Comment: Very nice, I did not know that incrementing a letter past Z would result in AA!

Comment: Yes, this seems to (almost) provide the desired feature. But I do not want to print the list, I want to modify (overwrite) the original file with the enumeration.

Comment: Take the output from Cyrus' script then mv it over the original file.  Trivial.  PS: let this be a lesson about the quality of questions :-)

Comment: @Birdie look at the other command line flags perl has. There is one for that.

Comment: @Nic3500: Sorry for asking a stupid question. But really, I am not that familiar with either Perl, sed or saving a print output, and when reading solutions to similar questions it seems to me that one would usually not start with a print if it is not among the desired features.

Comment: @Birdie: Your question was not stupid but unclear/incomplete.

Comment: @Cyrus: Thank you for your solution. But I cannot locate the relevant perl flag which will allow me to write to a file. My guess would have been -i, but it does not seem to work. :-/

Comment: @Birdie: *"I do not want to print the list, I want to modify (overwrite) the original file with the enumeration"* You don't say that anywhere in your question. You need to be much more careful to be clear and complete with your questions, or you will soon be looking at a question ban.

Comment: @Birdie: Replace `-e` with `-i -e`.

Comment: Thank you, @Cyrus! I tried writing '-e -i'. But it apparently does not commute.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting Cyrus' answer to add the `-p` command-line option and changing the code to overwrite the original file:

```
$ perl -pi -e 'BEGIN { $x="A" }; $_ = $x++ . " $_"' your_file_here
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed

```
sed -E 's/([^A-Z]+)([A-Z]+)(.*)/\2 \1\2\3/' infile
```

add -i to overwrite